# Tor connection in guest OS is being blocked by unknown firewall At Host OS part 2

Tags: help, support, firewall

a few days ago i have posted this:

I am having a problem setting up tor through virtual box and let me give you guys some details: I have installed tor bundle on win xp that is installed on virtual box but when i am trying to activate tor bundle it won't connect, it will get stuck in the "loading network status" level. I have malware anti bytes installed on the pc and norton anti virus. malware antybytes will show me message when i am trying to connect to tor like :"website blocked ip:61231 port" i will get a few messages like this and it just won't connect to tor on guest os. i tried to deactivate norton and malware antybytes but it still won't connect to tor. What else shall i try?

and i have gotten this answer from Alexey Vesnin:
Malwarebytes is blocking Tor - it's a known issue. If I got you right - you have two antiviruses on one PC, it's a bad idea nowdays: I remember 1994 - yes, then it made some sense, but not now. Some network filtering is remaining when the AV is deactivated, and - if your host is also Windows - it can activate windows defender+firewall when disabling other antivirus... Use network bridge for your virtual machine - it should keep you out of trouble. And feel free to ask further if it will not work - together we will solve this, don't worry!

I didn't know if i should respond over there in the answer section or i should just open a new question tab, so that is what i am doing.

So, i have removed malware bytes from my pc and i have stayed just with norton, but still i am not able to connect to tor through the guest os.
n.b what exactly and how exactly do i do the network bridge that you told me?
because when i am trying to bridge the virtual box network adapter it tells me that i can bridge it just to another lan network and my main network is wireless.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a bridge to the adapter you're using to talk to your LAN. For a wireless adapter there's no problem at all in VirtualBox - take a look at my screenshot: [image: Virtualbox Bridge for Wifi adapter]

Add your screenshot, OS version and details if you can't see your wifi adapter for a bridge